# Junk characters while reading text file in java

Tags: java

I have a java which calls windows bat file which does some processing and generates the output file.
`Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c "+filename);`
Now when reading the file from following program. (`filexists()` is function which checks whether file exists or not). Output file contains only single line

```
if ( filexists("output.txt") == true)    
{   String FileLine; 
    FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("output.txt");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));

    FileLine = br.readLine();
    fstream.close();
    filein.close();

}
```

Variable FileLine contains 3 junk charcters in the starting. I also checked few other files in the progam and no file has this issue except for the fact it is created with Runtime function.
`ï»¿9087`.
As you can see three junk characters are coming in the output file. When opened with Notepad++, i am not able to see those junk characters.

Please suggest

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is happening because you have not mentioned the file encoding while creating your FileInputStream.Assuming your file is UTF-8 encoded, you need to do something like this

```
   new FileInputStream("output.txt, "UTF-8"));
```

Change the encoding as per the encoding of your file

Answer (score 5):

That looks like the byte order mark for UTF-8 encoding.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark

Answer (score 1):

May be its an issue with file encoding. Though I am not sure.
Can you please try following piece of code and see if it works for you

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
new InputStreamReader( new FileInputStream("output.txt"), "UTF8"));

String str;

while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
  System.out.println(str);
}
```